Azure with Eplan platform
I've been attempting to create a VM in Azure with Windows 11, and now I'm trying to add the "Eplan Platform 2024" from the Azure Marketplace. However, during the implementation process, I encountered the following error:

The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because
it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. (Code:
ResourceDeploymentFailure)
The VM reported an error while processing the 'joindomain' extension
(publisher 'Microsoft.Compute' and type 'JsonADDomainExtension').
Error message: 'Exception(s) occurred while joining Domain
'trevi-env.com''. More troubleshooting information is available at
https://aka.ms/vmextensionwindowstroubleshoot. (Code:VMExtensionProvisioningError)

My VM was running while Azure was
implementing the Eplan Platform.
I'm relatively new to Azure and unsure what might be causing this issue. Can someone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem?
